# Converting xml object hierarchy to objects and adding to a list

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to xml , so please don't mind if it is too trivial question

Assume I have a xml file like below

```
 <Person>       
        <Name>John-Jaime-Winston Junior</Name>       
    </Person>
    <Person>       
        <Name>Steve</Name>
    </person
```

Now i will have a person object , Can i know how to read the xml and cover to a array of objects.

Finally i want something like a list which will have all person objects.

I am unable to get the start how to do this as i am new to xml

```
class person {

 string _name

 public string Name
        {
            get { return _name}
            set { _name= value; }
        }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that really the XML you're using?

Comment: @chaos pandioin , yes i am using xml , i just a sample code as i cannot post my entire xml , its almost the same concept

Comment: FYI: The sample is not valid XML, because XML requires there to be a single root node. Suggest changing it to something like ChaosPandion's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx), you can serialize and deserialize objects by this. just should define properties public

```
[Serializable()]
public class person 
{

        string _name

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name}
            set { _name= value; }
        }

}
```

and use it:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("c:\\out.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(sw,new Person{Name = "Test"});
        sw.Close();


        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\out.xml");
        var outVal = serializer.Deserialize(sr) as Person;
```

But for parsing xml in normal way you can use XDocument or XPath, ...

Comment: this is what i want , so that i can write one method which can pass any type of object

Comment: i was looking something like above and a generic method which takes the person and automatically converts to object , i achieved it somehow , if you have better code please post it.

Comment: @gov, you should read XmlSerializre link I left for you, serialization of object is a normal way of serialization, you can also do it with soap formatter, binaryformatter and DataContractSerializer, for example in remoting or WCF objects should be serialized to send and in receiver they should be deserialize, and this can achieve by this way, say what exactly you want, if I know I'll help you :)

Answer (score 3):

Given .NET 3.5 and System.Xml.Linq this is quite easy.

```
var q = from e in XElement.Parse(xml).Elements()
        select new Person() { 
            Name = e.Element("Name").Value 
        };

var p = q.ToList();
```

You will need to provide valid XML like what follows:

```
<People>
    <Person>
        <Name>Jim</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>Bill</Name>
    </Person>
</People>
```